# Camel XSLT2.0 Support

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I tried to integerate Camel to use XSLT2.0 but getting an exception as Could not "compile style sheet"

My camel config route is below

Also placed the xalan.jar and saxon9he.jar at JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed directory.  Any thing else I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add Saxon to your classpath to have XSLT 2.0 supported. The default xslt engine from the JDK/JVM only supports XSLT 1.x.
http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

You can add camel-saxon to the classpath to include saxon.

Also Camel would log which xslt engine it uses. Though I think you may need Camel 2.9 or 2.10 to do that, as we recently added that.